# dynamic drop down, show results

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a model, Firms, with the following attributes: state and name.  What I'd like to do is have the user view a list of names in a selected state.  I was able to get the states in a dropdown box, but am struggling to have the names appear below after selecting a state.  I looked throughout the options on here, but couldn't find a solution.  I presume I need some javascript?  Thanks for your help.  Below is my view code.

```
 <h4>Select a State</h4>
<%= select_tag :state, options_for_select(Firm.order(:state).uniq.pluck(:state)) %>
```

Here is an example of what I'd like the results to look like:

User selects the state: Pennsylvania

Pennsylvania names appear below:
Box Company
Car Company
.
.
.

Comment: Description of what this is supposed to do is really lacking in proper details. Provide proper html sample and expected results

Comment: just added an example @chartietfl.

Comment: And these names magically get found where?

Answer (score 1):

The user selects a state, a `javascript` `event` fires, an `ajax` call gets made and results gets showed under:

#### html

```
<%= select_tag :state, options_for_select(Firm.order(:state).uniq.pluck(:state)), id: "my-select" %>
<div id='names-wrapper'></div>
```

#### coffee

```
  $("#my-select").change ->
   state = $(this).val()
   alert(state)
   $.ajax
     url: "/firms/get_names"
     data:
       state: state
     success: (data) ->
       $('#names-wrapper').html('')
       $.each data, (index, value) -> 
         $('#names-wrapper').append(value)
```

#### routes

```
resources :firms do
  collection do
    get :get_names
  end
end
```

#### controller

```
class FirmsController < ApplicationControler
  def get_names
    state = params[:state]
    names = Firm.where(state: state).pluck(:name)
    return render json: names.to_json
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks @Marwen, I put this code in, but am not seeing any name results in the view.  When I inspect the page, I see no results either.  Is there an extra line of code I need to put into the view to see the names?

Comment: Have you added the `my-select` **id** to your `select` ?

Comment: @richiepop2 There is a mistyped indentation in the coffeescript, I fixed it. I added also an `alert` to verify that the change event is firing.